# Is it possible to get the docker container IP in Jenkins using the Docker plugin?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I am using the Jenkins Docker plugin in the pipeline to start a background mongodb container for testing, using:

```
stage('Start') {
  steps {
    script {
      container = docker.image('mongo:latest').run('-p 27017:27017 --name mongodb -d')
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the container IP address to be able to connect to it. I found some examples online mentioning `docker.inspect` and `docker.getIpAddress` methods, but they are just throwing errors, and according to the [source code for the Docker plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy) I believe they don't even exist.

Is there a way to get the IP address from the `container` object?

Comment: Is the build running inside a container, or directly on a node?  If the main build isn't in a container then you should be able to connect to `localhost` and the first `-p` port number; you shouldn't ever need to look up the Docker-internal IP address.

Comment: The agent where the pipeline is running is a docker agent, but I also have this other container with mongodb. So the test script is running outside this mongodb container, and it requires the url to connect to mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution (please test it on your own):

```java
stage('Start') {
  steps {
    script {
      def container = docker.image('mongo:latest').run('-p 27017:27017 --name mongodb -d')

      def ipAddress = null

      while (!ipAddress) {

        ipAddress = sh(
          returnStdout: true,
          script      : "docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mongodb"
        )

        if (!ipAddress) {
          echo "Container IP address not yet available..."
          sh "sleep 2"
        }

      }

      echo "Got IP address = ${ipAddress}."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a builtin way in the plugin, but this is similar to what I ended up doing. Thanks!